# I am trying to use TFS2015 to publish a website solution like VS2015 with Publish Web App

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, tfs-2015

I am using VS2015 and TFS2015.  With my website solution, I can successfully Publish a Web App with the (right-click) VS2015 option of Publish Web App and the transformations to Web.config.  I have tried to setup the same functionality with TFS2015 and the new Build Capabilities, but am not having any success.  Is there any guidance from Microsoft on this?  I have looked at various examples for the new TFS2015 Build capabilities, but do not see much functionality in publishing web sites like VS2015 easily does.

We previously used Website Deployment Projects in VS/TFS 2010, but they have been obsoleted.  Surely there must be a way to publish a Web site solution in TFS2015 like VS2015 supports.

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide more information of the fail reason?Did you get any error or  other tips?

Comment: Are you using the new build system?

Comment: I am using the new TFS 2015 Build system and the Visual Studio Build step.  It references the same solution file that I use in VS2015.  There is no failure.  The build script console window displays Getting the source files, and building the referenced dependent projects and shows the success for the build.  The problem is how do you specify the publish option the the VS2015 'Publsh Web App' functionality provides.  I would assume some form of the Publish Build Artifacts step would be used, but don't know how to specify the aspnet_merge that happens with publish and the transformations.

Answer (score 4):

The process to publish web site in TFS2015 vNext build is similar to process in TFS2013.

You need to add the followings to the MSBuild argument:

/p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:DeployTarget=MSDeployPublish /p:CreatePackageOnPublish=True /p:MSDeployPublishMethod=InProc /p:MsDeployServiceUrl=localhost /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site/TFSTest" /p:VisualStudioVersion=14.0 /p:UserName=

[image]